# "weaker" or "more weak"?

Tags: grammaticality

Which is grammatically correct?:

- She has become weaker lately.
- She has become more weak lately.

Answer (score 2):

Both are fully grammatical. As with most monosyllabic adjectives, the form *weaker* is more common, but the *more* form is always possible.

Comment: Right. And in some constructions, it's required, e.g, _She is more weak than (she is) hungry, I think_.